# Node JS PostgreSQL TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typeerror

In the following node js code:

```
function saveAction(request, response) {
  const movie = {
    id: request.body.id,
    title: request.body.title,
    year: request.body.year,    
  };
  model.save(movie).then(
   () => {
      response.redirect(request.baseUrl);
   },
    error => { 
       response.send(error);
   },
  );
}
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at saveAction (C:\MyNode\movie-db\movie\controller.js:37:20)
>   Row 37: model.save(movie).then(

How can I fix the error? 
Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Which postgresql package do you use?

Comment: It's : "pg": "^7.10.0". Based on a mysql-example from a book I tried to work with postgresql. I managed to do the connection and read a table ( SELECT * FROM ...).  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE lead to error.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'model' is undefined. You can use `then` only on promises therefore you need to associate the model as an object instance of the table first and then your save will work. It should be something like this:

```
let model = new Movie(movie)  //assuming you named your table model as Movie and this is a new record. 
let model = Movie.findOne({your condition to find goes here}); // if you are updating you can also use update function directly.
```

And after that you can use `model.save().then....`

I recommend using sequelize as an orm for postgresql. It will simplify your database operations a ton.

Comment: `model` doesn't seem to be `undefined`, but `model.save(movie)` is. Maybe this version doesn't use Promises, but a callback?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot in a file a "});" and the postgresgl syntax is different, I can not take over the mysql statment one to one. The code works now. 
I am able to use the main sql commands. Thanks for the well-intentioned advice.
Best regards